# Delegate types and covariance with a generic delegate type

Tags: c#, delegates, covariance

I would like to maintain a list of delegates (here: "mCommandHandlers"). Since they're generic delegates, I actually defined a second type of delegates such that I can maintain such a list:

```
public delegate void CommandHandler<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand;
public delegate void ICommandHandler(ICommand command);
Dictionary<Type, ICommandHandler> mCommandHandlers;
```

I would use the first type for compile-time advantages, such as knowing exactly what kind of TCommand is being used in the implementation of my delegate:

```
RegisterHandler<ResourceCommand>((command) =>
{
       if (command != null)
       {
            ResourceManager.ResourceReceived(command.ResourceName, command.ResourceHash, command.ResourceData);
       }
});
```

Inside RegisterHandler, I would now like to do the following:

```
public void RegisterHandler<TCommand>(CommandHandler<TCommand> handler) where TCommand : ICommand
{
      mCommandHandlers.Add(typeof(TCommand), handler);
}
```

But I get the following error message:

> Error 3   Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   `CommandHandler<TCommand>'` to
>   `'ICommandHandler'`

Why is this? Should the compiler see that in fact my first delegate type demands the argument to be at least of type ICommand, assuring that the delegate instance conforms to the signature of the second delegate type as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should the compiler see that in fact my first delegate type demands the argument to be at least of type ICommand, assuring that the delegate instance conforms to the signature of the second delegate type as well?

There are two problems here.

Firstly, delegate variance doesn't allow for an implicit reference conversion of one delegate type to another - it allows you to create a *new* delegate instance from a compatible existing one.

Secondly, you've got the variance the wrong way round `CommandHandler<TCommand>` will only accept a *specific* type of command... whereas `ICommandHandler` will accept *any* `ICommand`.

So suppose we could do this:

```
CommandHandler<FooCommand> fooHandler = HandleFoo;
ICommandHandler generalHandler = new ICommandHandler(fooHandler);
```

Then we could call:

```
generalHandler(new BarCommand());
```

... how would you expect the `HandleFoo` method to cope with that?

There *is* a conversion from `ICommandHandler` to `CommandHandler<TCommand>` for any particular `TCommand`, because when the new delegate is called, that will always be valid. Sample code:

```
using System;

delegate void CommandHandler<TCommand>(TCommand command)
    where TCommand : ICommand;
delegate void ICommandHandler(ICommand command);

interface ICommand {}

class Command : ICommand {}

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ICommandHandler x = null;
        CommandHandler<Command> y = new CommandHandler<Command>(x);
    }
}
```

I suggest you just change your dictionary to:

```
Dictionary<Type, Delegate> mCommandHandlers;
```

Then when you need to invoke any particular delegate, you'll need to cast to the right kind of handler - which I assume you'll know due to a type parameter at that point. Or you could create a proxy handler which performs the cast, as per Jared's answer.

Comment: I see now how I completely turned the covariance idea the wrong way :). My specific delegates can't be sitting around waiting to accept any kind of ICommand, as they should, making part of the mCommandHandlers. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the two delegate types simply aren't compatible.  In order to make this work you are going to need to add an indirection layer which converts the arguments between `ICommand` and `TCommand`.

```
public void RegisterHandler<TCommand>(CommandHandler<TCommand> handler)
  where TCommand : ICommand
{
  mCommandHandlers.Add(
    typeof(TCommand), 
    (command) => handler((TCommand)command);
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also thought about that kind of indirection, but I really wonder exactly why the compiler doesn't see them as compatible? Since delegates should be covariant and all code is there to demand that covariance.

Comment: @user1610325: See my answer - they're really *not* compatible the way round you're trying. They're compatible the *other* way round. Always think about "would it be valid to call the original delegate via the new one, regardless of the arguments?" - the compiler tries to make sure that always works.

Comment: @user1610325 - `Func` delegates are covariant in their output, but contravariant in their arguments. Your delegates don't have any variance annotations anyway.

Comment: @user1610325 delegates are only co / contra variant if they are explicitly labelled as such via `in` and `out` parameters.  Only one of your delegates is generic hence has potential for variance.  In this particular case though you could only use contravariance because all of the values are in input positions.  Contra variance would not allow for the type of conversion you desire here (allows the values to get more specific, not more general). Jon's explanation has some more detail you will be interested in